# Can't get background image to work properly in Django using %static%

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

This is the code for a website which changes background image when refreshed but am not able to modify it to work on Django

I have written the code for a website which changes it's background image when refreshed. It worked before but after trying it in Django, I tried to use %static% to display images now it's not changing the background image.

```js
function changeBackground() {
  var imagess = ["{% static \"images/ESOTSM.jpg\" %}","{% static \"images/arrival.jpg\" %}","{%        static \"images/arrival1.jpg\" %}","{% static \"images/asclearasday.jpg\" %}","{% static   \"images/batmanblue.jpg\" %}"]
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = x = 'url(' + imagess[randomNumber] + ')';
  console.log(imagess[randomNumber]);
  console.log(x)
}
window.onload = changeBackground;
```

```css
body{
background-image:url(".jpg");
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:black;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please title your question with text that describes your problem (as I've done for you here). Also, post your code inside of a Stack Snippet (the <> icon you see while editing your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only solution i can think of is to define a global variable in your Django template that holds the path to your static images, and then use that variable in your JavaScript code.

It looks like the issue might be with the way you are using Django's static template tag in your JavaScript code. When you use the static tag in your JavaScript, it is not being evaluated by Django and is instead being treated as a string literal.

Here is an example of what I mean:
Django template:

```
<script>
  window.staticPath = "{% static '' %}";
</script>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function changeBackground() {
  var images = [
    "img1.jpg",
    "img2.jpg",
    "img3.jpg",
    "img4.jpg",
    "img5.jpg"
  ];
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  var imagePath = window.staticPath + "images/" + images[randomNumber];
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imagePath + ')';
}

window.onload = changeBackground;
```

This should work as long as your Django template is correctly set up to serve your static files.